# Вместо 404 переходит на главную

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

При вводе неправильной ссылки, переходит на главную страницу, а должна на 404.
Нашел проблему, в **htaccess** убираю данную строку `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?news=$1 [L]` и 404 начинает корректно работать.

Но мне надо оставить её, т.к с её помощью у меня сокращаются ссылки.
Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: В index.php проверяете существование новости, если нет - `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); exit;`

Comment: Есть какая-нибудь ссылка на мануал как это сделать? или описать в кратце если получится? Как проверить существование новости

Comment: Вам мануалы по всем существующим движкам устанавливаемым на сайты?

Comment: Попробуйте так: ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?news=$1
```

Если перевести на человеческий язык:

Если файл не найден, то вместо `404` открой  `index.php` и передай `url` как параметр `news`.

Похоже что новости с таким `id|title` нет и он(index.php!) перенаправляет на главную.

Что бы поправить:

В `index.php`, если новости нет, перенаправить на `404.php`.
Сам `apache config` не трогайте.